# Javafx 8 NetBeans titlebar icon with native packaging

Tags: netbeans, deployment, javafx

I need some help with NetBeans and a JavaFX project
When I try to install an icon in the title bar of a Windows 7
Desktop application it will not show up
Here are the steps I have used to create and EXE file
Main Class adds the icon with this line of code that works in Eclipse
pStage.getIcons().add(new Image(“file:src/Photos/C.ico”));
Inno Setup 5.0 installed and in Path
the icon is 32 by 32 and 32 bit depth it was created with GreenFish Icon maker
the icon is under Source Package in a folder named Photos 
right click project select Properties select Deployment
check Enable Native Packaging 
set the path to the icon for Native Package Icons
src/Photos/C.ico
Run Clean and Build
Run Package As EXE

The only other concern I have is this output message
No base JDK Package will use system JRE
I see this as a separate issue so as a bonus question
can I ask for help with how to include the JDK or JRE
so this application is independent of what JRE if any
is installed on the end user machine.

A side note during development if I use C.bmp
in place of the ico file the title bar will display
the bmp. The bmp file will not work at build time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@James_Duh I have no idea why this works and I doubt you find this FIX anywhere else as I searched the net for why you need to use a bmp and ico file
Here is what I did with NetBeans 8.0.? and JDK1.8.0_51 on Windows 7
in the Main.class I used this line of code

```
Image ico = new Image("Photos/C.bmp"); NetBeans
Image ico = new Image("file:Photos/C.bmp"); Eclipse
```

Then in the Photos folder I placed an icon named C.ico 32 by 32
this icon is used to populate the installer EXE file 
which when you run the EXE file the icon will be displayed
in the Start Menu 
I also checked Desktop Icon and Start Menu shortcut under
Deployment in NetBeans Deployment screen

The Native Package deployment process in Eclipse is a real real **PAIN**
In the future I will make the switch to NetBeans IDE for this reason alone